# Python backtracing algorithm to solve sudokus

Tags: python, backtracking, sudoku

just starting with some python code and i was trying to make a sudoku solver using the backtracking algorithm posted [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku_solving_algorithms)

So i have this right now:

```
SUDOKU= [[0, 6, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0],
     [0, 0, 8, 3, 0, 5, 6, 0, 0],
     [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
     [8, 0, 0, 4, 0, 7, 0, 0, 6],
     [0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0],
     [7, 0, 0, 9, 0, 1, 0, 0, 4],
     [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
     [0, 0, 7, 2, 0, 6, 9, 0, 9],
     [0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 8, 2, 7, 0]]

     sublist = []

def validate(value, y, x, sudoku):

    # check linea
    for idx in range(0,9):
        if sudoku[y][idx] == value:
            return False   
    for idy in range(0, 9):
        if sudoku[idy][x] == value:
            return False
    return True


def validate_square(value, y, x, sudoku):

    if y < 3 and x < 3:
        aux_list = [aux_list[0:3] for aux_list in sudoku[0:3]]
        if value in [j for i in aux_list for j in i]:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    elif y < 3 and (x >= 3 and x < 6):
        aux_list = [aux_list[3:6] for aux_list in sudoku[0:3]]
        if value in [j for i in aux_list for j in i]:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    elif y < 3 and (x >= 6 and x < 9):
        aux_list = [aux_list[6:9] for aux_list in sudoku[0:3]]
        if value in [j for i in aux_list for j in i]:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    elif (y >= 3 and y < 6) and x < 3:
        aux_list = [aux_list[0:3] for aux_list in sudoku[3:6]]
        if value in [j for i in aux_list for j in i]:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    elif (y >= 3 and y < 6) and (x >= 3 and x < 6):
        aux_list = [aux_list[3:6] for aux_list in sudoku[3:6]]
        if value in [j for i in aux_list for j in i]:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    elif (y >= 3 and y <6) and (x >= 6 and x < 9):
        aux_list = [aux_list[6:9] for aux_list in sudoku[3:6]]
        if value in [j for i in aux_list for j in i]:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    elif (y >= 6 and y < 9) and x < 3:
        aux_list = [aux_list[0:3] for aux_list in sudoku[6:9]]
        if value in [j for i in aux_list for j in i]:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    elif (y >= 6 and y < 9) and (x >= 3 and x < 6):
        aux_list = [aux_list[3:6] for aux_list in sudoku[6:9]]
        if value in [j for i in aux_list for j in i]:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    elif (y >= 6 and y < 9) and (x >= 6 and x < 9):
        aux_list = [aux_list[6:9] for aux_list in sudoku[6:9]]
        if value in [j for i in aux_list for j in i]:
            return False
        else:
            return True
    else:
        return True

def auto_complete(sudoku):
    for idy in range(0,9):
        for idx in range(0,9):
            if sudoku[idy][idx] == 0:
                for attempt in range(1, 10):
                    if validate(attempt, idy, idx, sudoku) == True and validate_square(attempt, idy, idx, sudoku) == True:
                        sudoku[idy][idx] = attempt

if __name__ == "__main__":
    auto_complete(SUDOKU)
    for i in SUDOKU:
        print(i)
```

This is the solution i'm getting with it:

```
[9, 6, 3, 1, 8, 4, 7, 5, 0]
[4, 7, 8, 3, 9, 5, 6, 2, 0]
[2, 5, 0, 7, 6, 0, 8, 9, 1]
[8, 9, 5, 4, 3, 7, 1, 0, 6]
[1, 2, 6, 8, 5, 0, 3, 0, 7]
[7, 3, 0, 9, 2, 1, 5, 8, 4]
[5, 8, 9, 0, 7, 3, 4, 6, 2]
[3, 1, 7, 2, 4, 6, 9, 0, 9]
[6, 4, 0, 5, 1, 8, 2, 7, 3]
```

And this one is the expected one (right solution):
[sudoku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oev79.jpg)

At this point i have an algorithm which can partially do backtrack but when it comes to a value that dont fit its cell (line, row, square violations) its just leaves it blank, from wikipedia post i understand that i should go a position backwards (substracting 1 to idx maybe?) add 1 to that cell and revalidating that value.

Im quite lost, so any suggestions on how to improve this code in pythonic ways?

Also, is a list of lists the best way to struct the sudoku data? They seem to work a little bit different from arrays (which is where i come from, not an expert anyways)

Thank you all for reading!

Comment: I does not look like your `auto_complete` function does the backtracking described in wikipedia, if I understood correctly, because if a cell can't be validated, you have to move back, and here you are not doing that. So to navigate from cell to cell, I would do a while loop, and if a cell can't be validated, I decrement idx or idy.

Comment: The backtracing algorithm is a breadth first search algorithm which means its technically creating a tree/graph data structure as it fills in each square. When a it comes to a bad value it jumps back up to the lowest most correct point in the tree. that could be on square back or multiple lines back. You might have to store all previously visited board states to know how far back to go. Plasmas method would also work. Worse time complexity but easier to code. If you insert them into a tree structure you also have to make the tree.

Comment: i thought about it and its probably the way i will try to solve this but, whats the performance of a while beeing inside of a nested for loop? I mean, its not the case since both fors are small but is it a good practice or it would be recommended to approach from another way?

Comment: Also, in your code you choose to modify the sudoku _in place_. If you do so, while backtracking you must be careful not to change values that were set at the beginning of the sudoku.

Comment: http://norvig.com/sudoku.html this might help. He outlines a start to end tutorial on programming a brute force solution

Comment: Thank you all for the replies, @PlasmaBinturong well, this is another problem i faced with, which is a proper way of flaging initial values as initial values so the algorithm does not change them? ty very much Sam for the post it will help me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I want to point that better solution of "validate square" is:

```
square_x = x // 3 * 3
square_y = y // 3 * 3
for row in range(square_x, square_x + 3):
    for col in range(square_y, square_y + 3):
        if num == main_grid[row][col]:
            print(f"You can't put {num} in {x}|{y}.\n"
                  f"{num} already exists in {row}|{col}. "
                  f"[square: {x // 3}|{y // 3}]")
            return False
```

*the sudoku grid can be divided into 9 squares ;)*